# javascript didn't recognize python list

Tags: javascript, python, django

This my views.py

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.core import serializers

def get_contacts(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    cat_list = []

        cat_list = contact.objects.all()
        friend_list=serializers.serialize('json',cat_list)
        return HttpResponse(friend_list,mimetype="application/json")
```

and this is my js

```
$.get('/share_win/get_contacts/', function(data) {
    alert(data);
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: data
    });
}).fail(function(error) {
    alert('error');
});
```

And after running alert(data) it  types [object Object], ...[object Object], but it should print name1 not Object.
Any idea ??

Comment: Why exactly are you mixing django and flask. Also, wha's `RequestContext`? And why do you check `request.method` in a function that won't even be called for anything that's not GET?

Comment: most importantly: what is `autocomplete`

Comment: sorry , I edit my code , but problem is still the same

Comment: contact is table name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you want to return a list of strings instead of objects. If so then use `values_list()` method and use the `simplejson` to "serialize" this list:

```
cat_list = contact.objects.all().values_list('name', flat=True)
friend_list = simplejson.dumps(list(cat_list))
```

The `name` is the field in the `contact` model.

Comment: after adding values_list I'm getting the folowing error AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: Use `simplejson` instead of the `serialize()`.  See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

For your alert i would say try this,
But I seriously dont understand your code,

```
$.get('/share_win/get_contacts/', function(e) {
    alert(JSON.parse(e.data));
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: data
    });
}).fail(function(error) {
    alert('error');
});
```